# How can I end writing to file for cases where > is used to bypass console in Python

Tags: python, file-io, read-write

So I am executing come code:

```
python my_app.py > console.txt
```

So this allows me to generate a file on disk with all of the console print outs.

Then somewhere in the script I want to send the report in an e-mail. But whenever I do that I get a truncated version of the file. When the app closes the file has all of the information.

I tried this:

```
 my_file = open('console.txt', 'r+', 1)
        my_file.flush()
        os.fsync(my_file.fileno())
        my_file.close()

        time.sleep(60)

        filename = 'console.txt'
        with open(filename, "r+", 1) as attachment:
            print(attachment.readline(-20))
            attachment.flush()
            os.fsync(attachment.fileno())

            time.sleep(60)
            # Add file as application/octet-stream
            # Email client can usually download this automatically as
            # attachment
            part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        attachment.close()

        # # Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email
        encoders.encode_base64(part)

        # Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
        part.add_header(
            "Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename={}".format(filename),
        )

        # Add attachment to message and convert message to string
        email.attach(part)
```

But still the file gets sent truncated. Any ideas or tips on how to flush everything to disk, my manual triggers dont work here :(

Comment: Requiring the script to be invoked with a redirection is ugly and brittle. Maybe have it write to a temporary file or internal buffer for internal consumption as well as print to standard output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code moves the stream position (or file pointer) in the `readline(-20)` statement.

The file pointer needs to be moved back to the beginning of the file by calling `attachment.read(0)` before being read again, if the code is to read the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by running the following:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```